# how to retrieve data from database and place it into dropdown menu using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have wrote a simple Select SQL statement that will select all the data from the database, using this data i want it to display it on my drop down menu. This is my Ajax call:

```
var ajReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
$(document).ready(function () {
    AjaxMethod();
});

function AjaxMethod() {
    ajReq.abort();
    ajReq = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Services/Page.asmx/GetData",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {}
    });
}
```

This is my dropdown menu:

```
 <div class="dropdownBox">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" id="something" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Please Select you Data:
  <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">


            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

> so the question is that how do i get Javascript to display data into my dropdown menu, i am calling my AjaxMethod when the page is loaded. 
>   I have edited according to the answer but i get a error of: when i click on drop down menu i get drop down of [object Object], [object Object]... error . This applies to all the drop boxes i have. When i add a breakpoint to $each(data, function(i) - i get [object object] as message but when i click on + i can see all my data from the database but when i hoverover  and click on + it says: Children could not be evaluated. What does that means

Comment: `ajReq` is completely unnecessary, though it shouldn't cause a problem. You of course need to write code in the `success` handler that creates the html. The exact code depends entirely on what is being returned by your ajax call.

Comment: I wouldn't say unnecessary, for it helps prevent duo calls to this method. However, to remove `conflict`, you're going to want to change `ajReq.abort();` to `if (ajReq) ajReq.abort();`, otherwise you'll get a conflict as `ajReq` maybe nothing when it first reaches that line.

Comment: my Ajax method returns list of names, is it possible to show a little example? e.g. how do i like it to my twitter dropdown menu

Comment: Next you use your callback. `if (data) { $('.dropdown-menu').html(data) }` or whatever your `data` is in your callback.

Comment: I have tried this method too, i am getting an error as its describe in my updated question

Answer (score 0):

If `data` is an array of strings, you could do something like this untested example:

```
success: function (data) {
    var opts = '';
    $.each(data, function(i){
        opts += '<option>' + this + '</option>';
    };
    $('.dropdown-menu').html(opts);
}
```

Comment: in response body i get error of 500 'Parser Error' what does that means?

Comment: 500 level errors are server errors. You have an issue with your server side code. Put a breakpoint in your service code to determine what the issue is.

Comment: I was testing few things, and i notice a error so when i click on drop down menu i get drop down of [[object Object], [object Object]...] error.  When i add a breakpoint to $each(data, function(i) - i get [object object] as message but when i click on + i can see all my data from the database but when i hoverover <ops> and click on + it says: Children could not be evaluated. Also when clicking on the function in my request body their is nothing but response body has all the data i need.

Comment: Well, what is `data`? I indicated that this code would work for an array of strings, but you obviously are returning a complex type. I don't know anything about your complex type, so I can't advise. Figure out where your property of interest is on `data` and append it to the option string.

Comment: i am returning List<> of string, the list only contains 4 names. i dont see the reason why it should not work. The reason is because when i click + i can see all my data. So if my request body is empty then what does that means?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your `success` callback and look at `data`. Is it `['string1', 'string2', 'string3']`?

Answer (score 0):

- Make the ajax call
- In the script, query the database to get the rows with the info needed
- Return the resulting array of rows in json format
- Inside the callback function, decode the json encoded response into an js array using $.parseJSON function.
- Empty the ul element.
- Create li elements for each items in js array.

Be aware that if you like to have a event handler attached to lis, it has to be attached to the ul tag instead, like $('ul').on('click', 'li', function(){...});